# How to open a Intent with data according to the item clicked on a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity, parameters

I have a ListView, actually generated by parsing a XML file downloaded from Internet.

This XML file contains data about a person: IdNumber, Name, Age, PhotoURL, Birthday, Phone numbers, Email account, etc.

I get all the XML data when generating the ListView, but on each row I show some values of the person (not all), just name, age, photo (from the PhotoURL) and email.

I would like to get the "IdNumber" to parse it to the Activity that shows all the info, this activity should read the "IdNumber", get all the data of only that person and show it.

How can I parse a value that I'm not using on my ListView?

Thanks in advance,
Herni

Comment: Set up a simple [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) with fields for the data you're parsing out of the XML response, and add some getters/setters to access the data? You can then supply a collection of these POJOs to your list adapter and retrieve the relevant item when tapped. Heaps of examples out there to help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

For each row in the listView create an Object with all the fields you've originally parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You will create a model that like this:

```
public class Person
{
String idNumber,Name,Email;

public void SetIdNumber(String p_value)
{
  this.idNumber = p_value;
}
public void SetName(String p_value)
{
  this.Name= p_value;
}
public void SetEmail(String p_value)
{
  this.Email= p_value;
}

//Get Methods
public String GetIdNumber()
{
 return idNumber;
}
public String GetName()
{
 return Name;
}
public String GetEmail()
{
 return Email;
}
```

When you parse your xml you will create an ArrayList list; and fill after the 'list' you will use this everywhere you want. 
For example when you click your first item of your listview you could ;

```
    Person p = list.get(position that clicked your listview);
```

Now you will use your Person model. This is simple object oriant man.